# Is there a way to customise my pipeline failure report on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to have a report for our change failure rate in production. Currently the Pipeline failure report shows all failures at all stages of the pipeline. I want to be able to see failure stats on each individual stage.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: I don't think there is a way, the only filter I usually use is the branch one. 
The only way I think you might do this is through Power BI connecting the Azure DevOps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a easy and directory way to achieve this, since azure devops doesnot have this feature yet. You can have a try with Power BI as @ZetaPR suggested. There is example of showing [Pipeline stage wise failures sample report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-pipelines-stagewise-failures?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi) in Power BI provided by Microsoft.

You can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to Microsoft development team. Hope they can consider this feature and implementing it in the future rings.

[image]