# Is there a native function in azure devops for measuring Lead Time For Changes and Change Failure Rate metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, dashboard, metrics

I'm trying to create a dashboard with the Lead Time For Changes and Change Failure Rate metrics but I can't find a native Azure DevOps function or a simple solution for that. Has anyone seen something like this?

Comment: Hi, "but I can't find a native Azure DevOps function or a simple solution for that" Could you re-describe more details about scenario?

Comment: Well, in Azure DevOps there are widgets that help to extend measurement functionality. I would like to find a widget or something similar to measure production metrics. I really need to take these metrics and I am not finding a solution already ready for them

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948509